# Swing Nimbus LoweredBorder on Java 7

Tags: java, swing, border, nimbus

I have a Java Swing application using the Nimbus look and feel. I also use LowerBorder to layout some of components. This is working fine on Java 6 and earlier version, but I get a class not found exception on Java 7.

Any ideas why? I have checked Java 7's JavaDoc, it seems that this border has been removed. If this is the case, is there any work-around to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Rui

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: It seems to have a [package access only in JDK 7](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/javax/swing/plaf/nimbus/LoweredBorder.java.html)

Answer (score 4):

The package of that class has changed between Java 6: `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.LoweredBorder` and Java 7: `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.LoweredBorder`, hence the Class not found issue.

You should avoid trying to use restricted packages such as `com.sun.*`, since they are subject to arbitrary changes.

More generally, you should also avoid trying to manipulate low-level L&F stuffs and rather use the original API's to achieve what you want.

Comment: And `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.LoweredBorder` was public whereas `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.LoweredBorder` is not.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. LoweredBorder is a useful border, any chance I can still use it in Java 7?